# What's an example of an Aurelia app using Webpack 4.x?

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I'm trying to integrate the [aurelia-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin) version 3.0.0-rc.1 with Webpack 4.5. Here is what my webpack configuration looks like:

```js
const {AureliaPlugin} = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    main: "aurelia-bootstrapper",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          loader:'html-loader',
          exclude: path.resolve('src/index.html')
        },
        {
          test: /\.less$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"]
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
        },
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    chunkFilename: "[name].js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new AureliaPlugin({ aureliaApp: "app", dist: 'native-modules' }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'index.html',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    modules: ["./src", "./node_modules"],
  },
 devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    disableHostCheck: true,
    publicPath: '/',
    inline: true,
    port: 9000,
    hot: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    clientLogLevel: 'info',
    contentBase: './',
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: /node_modules/
    },
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

My index.html looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body aurelia-app="main">
</body>
</html>
```

When I run `webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.hmr.js`, I get this error in the browser:

```
aurelia-loader-webpack.js:187 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-framework
    at WebpackLoader.<anonymous> (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:187)
    at step (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:36)
    at Object.next (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:17)
    at aurelia-loader-webpack.js:11
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at ./node_modules/aurelia-loader-webpack/dist/native-modules/aurelia-loader-webpack.js.__awaiter (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:7)
    at WebpackLoader../node_modules/aurelia-loader-webpack/dist/native-modules/aurelia-loader-webpack.js.WebpackLoader._import (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:152)
    at WebpackLoader.<anonymous> (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:252)
    at step (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:36)
    at Object.next (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:17)
```

- **Library Version:**
  3.0.0-rc.1
- **Operating System:**
  Windows 10
- **Node Version:**
  8.9.0
- **NPM Version:**
  5.5.1
- **Webpack Version**
  4.5.0
- **Browser:**
  Chrome 65
- **Language:**
  ESNext

There doesn't seem to be any documentation for a Webpack 4 configuration that integrates the aurelia-webpack-plugin so I'm somewhat shooting in the dark here. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: After generating the example how do you use it using webpack --watch instead of au run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Aurelia application created by the Aurelia CLI uses Webpack 4 as of `0.33.0`. You can have it generate an app and then look at how it works.

Comment: Looks like just updating my package.json libraries to the latest versions via [ncu -u](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-up) fixed the problem. Thanks!